# How can I get the tac command on OS X?

Tags: osx, cat

I like to use `tac` to reverse the output of `cat`. However, it's not available in the Mavericks terminal. I tried to find it on MacPorts and again it's not available. Can anyone please show me how to get `tac`? It's very helpful for reading log files.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Yes:

- Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
- `brew install coreutils`
- <s>`ln -s /usr/local/bin/gtac /usr/local/bin/tac`</s> *apparently not needed with latest Homebrew, see comment by Ran Ever-Hadani below*

or use MacPorts to install `coreutils` in a similar way.

Comment: Addition to [grebneke](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32165/grebneke)'s answer: no need the soft link anymore. The g suffix is now only added if osx already has a command with that name, so tac is installed as tac, not gtac.

Comment: The soft link is still needed when using MacPorts.

Answer (score 102):

On OS/X like on many systems (BSDs, Solaris, AIX, IRIX...), the functionality of GNU `tac` is available in [`tail` with the `-r`  option](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/tail/). So no need to install GNU `tac`:

```
tail -r the-file
```

Comment: So, `alias tac='tail -r'` will do the trick for OP!

Comment: [Well, actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html) using a shell alias may fail because aliases don't transfer into shell scripts. Use a function like `tac() { tail -r -- "$@"; }`

Comment: Does it have options like `-rs` which will let you reverse at char level instead of new lines?

Comment: @SubinSebastian, I've updated the link to the man page which Apple no longer makes available. But in short, no BSD `tail` has no equivalent of GNU `tac`'s `-s` option.

Answer (score 1):

One temporary solution could be:

```
alias tac='perl -e "print reverse(<>)"'
```

Comment: This just caused me to learn that `<>` doesn't only read from STDIN, but optionally from `@ARGV`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020883/less-than-and-greater-than-symbols-together I still don't know if `reverse` will load the whole file into memory before outputting the lines in reverse order. That would be terrible.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, > ...STDIN, but optionally from @ ARGV : yes that is what <> is for. > ... will load the whole file into memory... : YES, IT WILL! (avoid doing this with gigabyte files)

Answer (score 0):

Install gnu coreutils already compiled with [Rudix](http://rudix.org):

```
sudo rudix install coreutils
```

Or download and gui install [Rudix coreutils](http://rudix.org/packages/coreutils.html)