# A graded print of asterisks

Tags: shell-script, scripting

im a beginner,
And i want to writing a script ('for' loop) -

- Requests a number
- Multiply the number by 2 and start a raw of asterisks
  And presents as here: (for example the number is 4)

```
********
 ******
  ****
   **
  ****
 ******
********
```

Comment: Please clarify further.

Comment: I'm trying to learn and do not understand how to do it at all.

Comment: Does your assignment specify which shell to use?

Comment: Hi, in ubunto and for or while loops

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Number please: ' n

{
        for (( i=0; i<n-1; ++i )); do
                printf '%*.*d\n' "$(( 2*n-i ))" "$(( 2*(n-i) ))" 0
        done

        for (( i=n-1; i>=0; --i )); do
                printf '%*.*d\n' "$(( 2*n-i ))" "$(( 2*(n-i) ))" 0
        done
} | tr 0 '*'
```

The above script reads a number from the user into the variable `n`.  It then creates the shape in two arithmetic `for` loops.

The first loop creates the top half of the shape, while the second loop creates the middle `**` and the lower half of the shape.

The `printf` statement in each loop is identical, and only the value of `i`, the loop variable, changes.

The `printf` format used here, `%*.*d`, means "allocate space according to the first argument, to print a zero-filled integer with the width of the second argument".  The actual integer to print is `0` (the third argument).  The 1st and 2nd arguments given to `printf` causes it to print triangular shapes of `0` as `i` changes.

The `0` characters are then changed into `*` characters using `tr`.

Testing:

```
$ bash script.sh
Number please: 10
********************
 ******************
  ****************
   **************
    ************
     **********
      ********
       ******
        ****
         **
        ****
       ******
      ********
     **********
    ************
   **************
  ****************
 ******************
********************
```

See also `man printf`.

Comment: you can save the second for-loop by storing the first loop result into a temp variable then first print itself next print `tac`ed version `printf '%s\n' "$tmp"; printf '%s\n' "$tmp"|tac`

Comment: @αғsнιη Ah, yes, if I had `tac` on my non-Linux system... :-) But still, good call. I might investigate it later.

Comment: then you can have `tail -r` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114043/72456