# Remove duplicates by adding numerical suffix

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, python

How do I append a numerical suffix to lines to remove duplicates?

**Pseudo code:**

```
if currLine.startsWith("tag:")
  x = numFutureLinesMatching(currLine)
  if (x > 0)
    currLine = currLine + ${x:01}
```

**Input file**

```
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
```

**Desired output**

```
tag:20230901-FAT-02
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT-01
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX-01
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
```

**Notes:**

1. The final duplicate must remain unchanged.
2. The earlier duplicates can have any suffix to be unique, so I chose a countdown.
3. Awk seems to be a good choice, but any common scripted language will work.

Comment: A countdown requires more work to implement and more time to execute than a countup because you don't know how many of X you have until you've gone through the input once so a countdown requires 2 passes of the input to determine the starting count value(s). So if it doesn't matter to you which way it goes - implement a countup, not a countdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` can take arbitrary array indices - even a whole record ("line").

Make a regex match for `tag:` and start the counter, but correct by one due to the first match

```
awk '$0 ~ /^tag:/ { n[$0]++?$0=sprintf("%s-%02d",$0,n[$0]-1):1 }  1'
```

To make it a countdown, use `tac` twice:

```
tac infile | 
awk '$0 ~ /^tag:/ { n[$0]++?$0=sprintf("%s-%02d",$0,n[$0]-1):1 }  1' |
tac
```

Comment: Perfect!  This solution worked better in my outer script where I had to pipe to and from this script.

Comment: You could alternatively write it as `awk '{print $0 (/^tag:/ && cnt[$0]++ ? sprintf("-%02d",cnt[$0]-1) : "")}' file` using the shorthand `/^tag:/` for `$0 ~ /^tag:/` and avoiding assigning to $0 which could cause awk to unnecessarily re-split the record into fields.

Answer (score 3):

##### Here we go, exactly as required:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{
        if (/^tag:/) {
            a[$1]++
        }
        next
    }
    {
        c=--a[$1]
        if (c>0) {
            printf "%s-%.2d\n", $1, c
        } else {
            print
        }
    }
' file file
```

#### With explanations:

```
awk '
    # first block for first file
    NR==FNR{                           # first file
        if (/^tag:/)                   # if the line starts with ^tag:
            a[$1]++                    # increment array a with key as column 1
        next                           # stop processing this line
    }                                                                   
    # 2th block for second file
    {
        c=--a[$1]                      # c = decrement array a with key as column 1
        if (c>0) {                     # ... pretty simple, no ?
            printf "%s-%.2d\n", $1, c  # %s = string %.2d integer, zero pading
        } else {                 
            print                      # else, print current line
        }
    }                                         
' file file
```

##### Output

```
tag:20230901-FAT-02
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT-01
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX-01
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my (%h, $c);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^tag:/) {
        $c = sprintf "%.2d", ++$h{$_};
        if ($c>1) {
            say $_ . "-" . $c;
        } else {
            say;
        }
    } else {
        say $_;
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
./script file
```

#### Output:

```
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT-02
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX-02
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT-03
val:1500
```

Comment: The output file isn't quite right here.  Appreciate the effort though.

Comment: What is not quite right? Be precise. Removed duplicated as requested

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %hash; put /^tag\:/ && %hash{$_}++ ?? $_ ~ sprintf("-%02d", %hash{$_}-1) !! $_;'   file
```

Above is the Raku version of an excellent `awk` answer posted by @EdMorton in a comment.

Start by calling Raku at the commandline with the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. Before entering the linewise code `BEGIN` by declaring a `%hash`. Run the `put`... statement over the input. If the line `/^tag:/` starts with `tag:` add the line to the `%hash` and `++` increment its value.

This `&&` conditional forms the beginning of Raku's "**Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False**" ternary operator. If True, the `$_` line is out`put` with the line's value minus one appended (value decoded using `%hash{$_}` ). If False, the line is out`put` unchanged.

Sample Input:

```
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
```

Sample Output:

```
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT-01
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX-01
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT-02
val:1500
```

Above implements a count-up suffix, leaving the earliest `tag:` lines unchanged. To implement a count-down suffix that leaves the final `tag:` lines unchanged, use `tac` twice as instructed in the accepted answer by @FelixJN. Below, the answer implemented on MacOS which uses `tail -r` instead of `tac`:

```
~$ tail -r  Steve_suffix.txt | raku -ne 'BEGIN my %hash; put /^tag:/ && %hash{$_}++ ?? $_ ~ sprintf("-%02d", %hash{$_}-1) !! $_;' | tail -r
tag:20230901-FAT-02
val:1034
tag:20230901-FAT-01
val:1500
tag:20230901-LAX-01
val:8934
tag:20230901-SMF
val:2954
tag:20230901-LAX
val:1000
tag:20230901-FAT
val:1500
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114043
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_??_!!
https://raku.org